# Harmon.ie An internal error has occurred

Tags: harmon.ie

I am promted with the following error when trying to move an folder inside harmon.ie outlook add-in.
I am moving a subfolder to another folder.
I’ve got a folder named Test1 containing a folder named Test1.1.
I’m trying to move Test1.1 to Test2 but get this error:
[internal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tlns.png)

Answer (score 0):

Would you please install the version at:
ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/HarmonieSharePointSetup.x86.msi

Let me then know how it goes.

Regards,

----- Jean